# Exception in thread "httpclient-dispatch-1" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.net.ssl.SSLParameters.setApplicationProtocols([Ljava/lang/String;)V

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

My jdk version is 1.8_0_151. I tried to change into version 144 or 191 but neither works.

httpclient5,org.apache.httpcomponents.core5 version are both 5.2.1

It seems that upgrading to jdk11 can solve the issue, but I have to continue using jdk8, so is there any good solution?

Error info:

> Exception in thread "httpclient-dispatch-1" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.net.ssl.SSLParameters.setApplicationProtocols([Ljava/lang/String;)V
> at org.apache.hc.client5.http.ssl.DefaultClientTlsStrategy.applyParameters(DefaultClientTlsStrategy.java:108)
> at org.apache.hc.client5.http.ssl.AbstractClientTlsStrategy.lambda$upgrade$0(AbstractClientTlsStrategy.java:138)
> at org.apache.hc.core5.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.initialize(SSLIOSession.java:293)
> at org.apache.hc.core5.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.beginHandshake(SSLIOSession.java:268)
> at org.apache.hc.core5.reactor.InternalDataChannel.startTls(InternalDataChannel.java:258)
> at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.nio.DefaultManagedAsyncClientConnection.startTls(DefaultManagedAsyncClientConnection.java:158)
> at org.apache.hc.client5.http.ssl.AbstractClientTlsStrategy.upgrade(AbstractClientTlsStrategy.java:111)
> at org.apache.hc.client5.http.ssl.DefaultClientTlsStrategy.upgrade(DefaultClientTlsStrategy.java:48)
> at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.nio.DefaultAsyncClientConnectionOperator.upgrade(DefaultAsyncClientConnectionOperator.java:179)
> at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.nio.PoolingAsyncClientConnectionManager.upgrade(PoolingAsyncClientConnectionManager.java:505)
> at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.async.InternalHttpAsyncExecRuntime.upgradeTls(InternalHttpAsyncExecRuntime.java:249)
> at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.async.AsyncConnectExec.proceedToNextHop(AsyncConnectExec.java:323)
> at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.async.AsyncConnectExec.access$000(AsyncConnectExec.java:82)
> at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.async.AsyncConnectExec$4.completed(AsyncConnectExec.java:298)
> at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.async.AsyncConnectExec$6.completed(AsyncConnectExec.java:423)
> at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.async.HttpAsyncMainClientExec$1.consumeResponse(HttpAsyncMainClientExec.java:224)
> at org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.nio.ClientHttp1StreamHandler.consumeHeader(ClientHttp1StreamHandler.java:243)
> at org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.nio.ClientHttp1StreamDuplexer.consumeHeader(ClientHttp1StreamDuplexer.java:348)
> at org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.nio.ClientHttp1StreamDuplexer.consumeHeader(ClientHttp1StreamDuplexer.java:80)
> at org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.nio.AbstractHttp1StreamDuplexer.onInput(AbstractHttp1StreamDuplexer.java:298)
> at org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.nio.AbstractHttp1IOEventHandler.inputReady(AbstractHttp1IOEventHandler.java:64)
> at org.apache.hc.core5.http.impl.nio.ClientHttp1IOEventHandler.inputReady(ClientHttp1IOEventHandler.java:41)
> at org.apache.hc.core5.reactor.InternalDataChannel.onIOEvent(InternalDataChannel.java:142)
> at org.apache.hc.core5.reactor.InternalChannel.handleIOEvent(InternalChannel.java:51)
> at org.apache.hc.core5.reactor.SingleCoreIOReactor.processEvents(SingleCoreIOReactor.java:178)
> at org.apache.hc.core5.reactor.SingleCoreIOReactor.doExecute(SingleCoreIOReactor.java:127)
> at org.apache.hc.core5.reactor.AbstractSingleCoreIOReactor.execute(AbstractSingleCoreIOReactor.java:86)
> at org.apache.hc.core5.reactor.IOReactorWorker.run(IOReactorWorker.java:44)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Please don't post code as picture, copy paste the relevant code and format it accordinlgy in question

Comment: Sorry, I can't believe you. That method did not exist (and work) in 8u151 or any other update of 8 below 8u251. 8u251 up does support it and should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

in Java 8, the method setApplicationProtocol has an array of String (also String[]) as parameter (but in Oracle's Java 11 too )

see : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLParameters.html

Comment: 8 has it only in update 251 up, but the version info in javadoc doesn't distinguish between updates.